# How to Configure MySQL for Percona Monitoring and Management

Tags: mysql, percona, query-analyzer

I can not get any analytics from **_PMM Query Analytics** showing 

[image]

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/conf-mysql.html this is that link. I changed the configuration as mentioned in this page, but after that pmm is not monitoring automatically! What should I do after changing those configurations.
 Do anyone know how to configure PMM-Client properly to get Query Analytics?
I'm using percona v5.7

Comment: Where does that link take you?

Comment: @RickJames question updated!

Comment: You might get more traction at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After configuring the percona server as instructed in https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/conf-mysql.html

1. go to _PMM Add instance in pmm webpage, and add Database name, user,
   password and click add.
2. wait few seconds pmm will start to show you the metrics needed.